# How to append HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am building up an HTML element using

```
$(this).html(' my html here');
```

There are many elements I need to add here with different CSS. So what I want is I should be able to do append another HTML here

```
$(this).html(' my html here');
$(this).html.append(' another html here');
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just use `$(this).append();`. Which is more than enough.

Comment: This is my exact html `$(this).parent().html('<span class=\"asset_value\">'+ new_comment +'</span>.css('color', 'red');
   $(this).append('<span id=save onclick=\"update(cellreport_id , new_comment)\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk pull-right\">&nbsp;</span>');` Its not working here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First declare.

```
var html = "";
html += "<span class="spnBlack"> First Content </span>";
html += "<p class="pRed">Second Content</p>";
$(this).html(html);
```

And in css file define

```
.spnBlack
{
  background-color: black;
}
.pRed
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Please avoid inline css.

Comment: This is good but I also want to add certain css styling to the elements individually. For eg: I want my span to be in black and <p> to be in red.  I used to do this by $(this).html('my html here').css(styling here)

Comment: this is good in terms of performance - you create a string of the code you want to append and then you append it - causing a single change to the DOM - far better than multiple .append() functions which alter the DOM each time. I also agree with @Shree regarding inline styling - best if you an get into a habit of keeping it separate.

Answer (score 6):

You can create an html element like this:

```
var p = $('<p>').html('Hello world');
```

This still not "exists" in your page, you need to append it to your selector using both `append` or `appendTo` (depending from the "point of view"):

```
$(this).append(p);
```

or

```
p.appendTo($(this));
```