# jQuery click event then create multiple group of divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have jQuery click event which is create group of div or container for every clicking the button . All I want is to create a container every click on a button.

Here is the HTML container create on every button click.

```
<button type="button" id="add_container">Add Container</button

<div class="container">
 <div class="label">
  <span>I'm the Label</span>
 </div>
 <div class="margin-select">
  <div class="padding-select">
   <select class="select2>
    <option>Choose 1</option>
    <option>Choose 2</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#add_container').on('click', function(){
  //add a container every click event <div class="container">...</div>
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append HTML using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543899/how-to-append-html-using-jquery)

Comment: If the `.container` element always exists in the DOM when the page loads then you can use [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone) and [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append)

Answer (score 3):

First Create a dummy div as shown below -

HTML -

```
<button type="button" id="add_container">Add Container</button

<div class="repeat_container"></div>
```

JQuery -

```
$('#add_container').on('click', function(){
   var html = '<div class="container"><div class="label"><span>I'm the Label</span></div><div class="margin-select"><div class="padding-select"><select class="select2><option>Choose 1</option><option>Choose 2</option></select></div></div></div>'; 
  $('.repeat_container').append(html);
});
```

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Use `clone()` with `.insertAfter`.

Example:

```js
$('#add_container').on('click', function() {
  $(".container:first").clone().insertAfter("div.container:last")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="add_container">Add Container</button

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="label">
      <span>I'm the Label</span>
    </div>
    <div class="margin-select">
      <div class="padding-select">
    <select class="select2">
    <option>Choose 1</option>
    <option>Choose 2</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a container wrapper and append a child to it:

**HTML**:

```
<button type="button" id="add_container">Add Container</button>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="label">
            <span>I'm the Label</span>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-select">
            <div class="padding-select">
                <select class="select2">
                    <option>Choose 1</option>
                    <option>Choose 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('#add_container').on('click', function(){

    console.log('Clicked!', 'add_container');

    $('.wrapper').append(
        '<div class="container">'
        + '<div class="label">'
            + '<span>I\'m the Label</span>'
        + '</div>'
        + '<div class="margin-select">'
            + '<div class="padding-select">'
                + '<select class="select2">'
                    + '<option>Choose 1</option>'
                    + '<option>Choose 2</option>'
                + '</select>'
            + '</div>'
        + '</div>'
    + '</div>');
})
```